# Adenium Boehmianum branches

Tags: plant-care, growth, succulents

Is there a trick to get my Adenium Boehmianum to sprout new branches?  It has never grown any more branches than when I bought it more than 5 years ago.  I just repotted it in proper soil with lots of drainage holes in the pot.  I am in AZ and it has just started sprouting leaves.  It goes into the garage when temperature drops below 45 degrees.  I must admit I have not been good about fertilizing.

Comment: A picture really helps!

Comment: Very poisonous...they use the sap to dip arrowheads in for better killing...if you have just re-potted this plant, leave it alone for now.  Re-potting is stressful.  Don't overwater and let us know what you have done already for type of soil (hopefully a sterilized potting soil purchased in a bag), last time you fertilized, what you added, where you are keeping this guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I knew nothing of this plant before today but I read a really interesting paper put out by the University of Florida that provided the advice below.

There's a few different types of adenium boehmianum, and some are naturally bushy while others tend to have just a few stems until they mature fully.

If your Adenium Boehmianum is getting leggy and you need to encourage branching, pinch back or remove a few inches of stem. Prune just above the leaves and it will be more likely to result in multiple branches than if you prune further down on the plant on bare stem. You can do this once a year, preferably from February to September. Trying to do this during winter often fails to generate healthy branching. If you do any of this be VERY careful. The sap, I'm sure you know, is highly poisonous.

If you provide pictures of your plant, someone may be able to help you further.

Comment: That all said, reading more on the subject I'd advise that unless the plant is stressed by not having enough branches, or is becoming dangerously top heavy, you consider letting it just be. It should branch out eventually if given proper growing conditions.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm guessing mine may be of the needing to mature type as the leaves are on the ends of all stems and there would be no place to trim unless I trimmed off the leaves.  I'm thinking I will leave it be and concentrate on better fertilizing for a couple of years.  Maybe the new space in the new pot will help.